# HTML sortable with more cells in one row?

Tags: html, html-table, row, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

**I would like to know how can I drag and move a row that have more cells?
The draging is working but when I release the mouse, that doesn't paste in, just revert back to original position.**

I attached two images with the resoults:
[image]

These codes are part of the big PHP project.

```
    echo '<form id="formName" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table class="draganddrop" width="980" cellspacing="20" table style="font-family:arial; font-size:20px;";>
<tr>
<td width="20" valign="top"><input type="image" formaction="print-delete.php?id='.$row['id'].'" width="20" height="20" src="/megrendelesek/images/print.svg"></td>
<td style="font-weight:bold; color: '.${'tablerow'.$row['id']}.'" width="105" valign="top" align="center" >'.$row["atveheto"].'</td>
<td style="color: '.${'tablerow'.$row['id']}.'" width="120" valign="top" >'.$row["megrendelo"].'</td>
<td style="font-weight:bold; color: '.${'tablerow'.$row['id']}.'" width="90" valign="top" >'.$row["cleanrovidnevek"].'</td>
<td style="color: '.${'tablerow'.$row['id']}.'" width="30" valign="top" align="center">'.$row["db"].'</td>
<td style="color: '.${'tablerow'.$row['id']}.'" width="40" valign="top" align="center" >'.$checksum.'</td>
<td style="color: '.${'tablerow'.$row['id']}.'" width="100" valign="top">'.$row["uzenet"].'</td>
<td style="color: '.${'tablerow'.$row['id']}.'" width="100" valign="top">'.$row["telepules"].'</td>
<td style="color: '.${'tablerow'.$row['id']}.'" width="80" valign="top" align="right">'.$row["vegosszeg"]. " Ft".'</td>
<td width="0"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'" /></td>
<td width="40" valign="top"><input type="image" formaction="delete.php?id='.$row['id'].'" width="20" height="20" src="/megrendelesek/images/trash.svg"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
';


<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.2/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
           $('.draganddrop').sortable({
          });

</script>
```

Whit this I can change colums, but I don't need it, I would like to change rows:

```
$(".draganddrop").children('tbody')
    .children('tr').sortable({
    });
```

Any idea would be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: One more thing: all rows are new tables, I think that way I can't change rows. How can I sort in multiple tables? I tried with div, without success.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
<div class="wrapper"> 
...//Different tables that generate PHP
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
     $('.wrapper').sortable({
    connectWith: $('.wrapper')
    });
</script>
```